# PM2 is catching errors before they reach 'uncaught Exception' in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

**Hey Guys,**
I am running a discordbot with Discord.js in Node.js. My goal is to run it via pm2 on a Linux Ubuntu Server.

I want to build a cleanup process *before* exiting the program on *uncaught Exception*.

However when I throw a sample error *and* run it via pm2 *uncaught Exception* is not reached, pm2 is just logging the error and continue running the script.
**When running it directly with Node.js, without pm2 everything works as expected.**

Here is my code:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', async (err, origin) => {
    console.log('test')
    // await Cleanup();
    process.exit(1);
});
```

Here the console output running it with pm2:

```
Error: Test error
at Object.execute (script xxxx)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async xxx
```

As you can see pm2 is kind of preventing the Test error to reach *uncaughtException*. Pm2 is not restarting the script, and is not logging 'test'

I also tried catching the error via *SIGINT* or *SIGTERM* but none of these are working.

Is there an option in pm2 to disable this behavior?

**Thanks for any help!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function in which the error is thrown is `async`.
That led me to the docs of the [unhandledRejection](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#event-unhandledrejection) event.

In addition to *uncaughtException* I added *unhandledRejection*:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', async (err, origin) => {
  await Cleanup(...); //my own cleanup
  process.exit(0);
});

process.on('unhandledRejection', async (reason, promise) => {
  await Cleanup(...); //my own cleanup
  process.exit(0);
});
```

Now pm2 is restarting after a `cleanup` whenever an uncaught Error/Exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

PM2 automatically restart applications when they crashed or terminate.

As i remember, you can not disable this: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/restart-strategies/

**UPDATE**

Normally `process.exit(0);` will restart the pm2 process.

You also have a workaround to force restart from within your app.
You need to start your app with the `--watch` parameter:

```
pm2 start app.js --watch
```

Thus, you just need to write/modify/delete a temp file in a directory inside your application directory. When pm2 detect new file it will restart your app. It's not a clean solution, but this work.

Comment: Thank your for your answer.
Unfortunately, pm2 does not restart the script at all it keeps running. 
Your answer is my goal, I want pm2 to restart the script and not to disable that auto restart.

Comment: @Huetti Ok, i have not understand your need of restarting the app. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, this seems promising, I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: It is a solution for errors you can predict, but I can't cover all my statements in try catch, when I am not sure if they will never throw an unexpected error.

Sometimes, when for example the db connection throws an error or a sql statement I want a restart.

Comment: I'm not shure that restarting on each errors is a good pattern. If you restart on an sql  error statement or whatever instead of dealing with it (logging, e-mail alerts, or everything else) you will stop all the others user request that are on the execution loop.